# Почему в поле ввода не работают сочетания клавиш буфера обмена на русской раскладке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Использую поле ввода `tkinter.ttk.Entry`. На русской раскладке комбинации `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+X` и `Ctrl+V` не работают. Но стоит переключить раскладку на английскую, как они начинают работать. Как заставить их работать независимо от раскладки?
Также не работают `Ctrl+Z`, `Ctrl+Shift+Z` и `Ctrl+Y` независимо от раскладки.

Comment: какая ОС? версии? пользуйся shift+insert

Comment: @eri Windows 7. Python 3.4. Shift+Insert работает, но не привыкать же мне к новым комбинациям? Хотя бы потому, что на ноутбуках не всегда можно успешно ими пользоваться.

Comment: попробуй актуальную версию питона